# How to get a list of all venues in Here API?

Tags: here-api

I am trying to get a list of all venues available through the Here API by requesting a [venue index](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/venue-maps/topics/resource-type-venues-index.html). My url looks as follows(with the strings replaced where necessary):

> static-3.venue.maps.cit.api.here.com/1/models-poi/index_bb.js?Policy={Policy}&Signature={Signature}&Key-Pair-Id={Key Pair}&app_id={App Id}&app_code={App Code}

This returns a JSON table, which I want, but I only have 155 entries, although there are clearly [more](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/venue-maps/topics/coverage-venue-maps.html). Does anyone know why I don't get the full list? Thanks. Below is the first couple lines of the output I get.

> JSON.venues([{ "gml:id" : "DM_8961", "bb": [ [52.4564118412704,13.384279785476354],[52.454433435991014,13.388207656793229] ]},{ "gml:id" : "DM_10465", "bb": [ [52.43143833815419,13.453328297714588],[52.4288047627723,13.45769174285097] ]},{ "gml:id" : "DM_17394", "bb": [ [52.475570406808345,13.458645521436816],

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting to a CIT Environment where not all Venue Data is exposed.